# My makefile isn't working

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to C++, switching over from Java for a class I'm taking in college. In our first assignment we have to write several makefiles for our code. My first makefile isn't working - it always complains about an error in "TempControlTest: undefined reference to 'BangBangControl::XXXX', where XXXX a function in BangBangControl (I get errors for every function in BangBangControl). I've been looking around online and all the makefile examples look slightly different so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I'll post all my code below, if anyone could just give me a little help, that would be AWESOME. Also, this is due tonight, so any quick help is appreciated so much. If you're still here, thanks very much!

HeatingUnit.h:

```
#ifndef HEATINGUNIT_H
#define HEATINGUNIT_H

class HeatingUnit {

private:
        bool on;
        int temp;

public:
        HeatingUnit(bool o, int t);
        void turnOn();
        void turnOff();
        int tick();
};

#endif
```

HeatingUnit.cpp:

```
#include "HeatingUnit.h"

HeatingUnit::HeatingUnit(bool o, int t) {
        on = o;
        temp = t;
}

void HeatingUnit::turnOn() {
        on = true;
}

void HeatingUnit::turnOff() {
        on = false;
}

int HeatingUnit::tick() {
        if(on) return ++temp + 1;
        else return --temp;
}
```

BangBangControl.h:

```
#ifndef BANGBANGCONTROL_H
#define BANGBANGCONTROL_H

#include "HeatingUnit.h"

class BangBangControl {

private:
        int tempToKeep;
        HeatingUnit unit;

public:
        BangBangControl(int ttk, bool on, int initTemp);
        void setTemp(int t);
        int getTemp();
        void update();
};

#endif
```

BangBangControl.cpp:

```
#include "HeatingUnit.h"
#include "BangBangControl.h"

BangBangControl::BangBangControl(int ttk, bool on, int initTemp) 
: unit(on, initTemp) {
        tempToKeep = ttk;
}

void BangBangControl::setTemp(int t) {
        tempToKeep = t;
}

int BangBangControl::getTemp() {
        return tempToKeep;
}

void BangBangControl::update() {
        int currentTemp = unit.tick();
        if(currentTemp > tempToKeep + 2) unit.turnOff();

        else if(currentTemp < tempToKeep - 2) unit.turnOn();
}
```

TempControlTest.cpp:

```
include <iostream>
#include "BangBangControl.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
        BangBangControl bang(100, false, 60);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                bang.update();
                cout << bang.getTemp() << " ";
                if(i % 10 == 9) cout << endl;
        }
}
```

And finally, Makefile_Executable:

```
all: TempControlTest

TempControlTest: TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.o
        g++ -o TempControlTest TempControlTest.cpp

BangBangControl.o: BangBangControl.cpp HeatingUnit.o
        g++ -c BangBangControl.cpp

HeatingUnit.o: HeatingUnit.cpp
        g++ -c HeatingUnit.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf *.o TempControlTest
```

Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't *linking* your objects together.

You've got two lines *compiling* `BangBangControl.cpp` and `HeatingUnit.cpp` to two `.o` files (although I doubt you need to have `BangBangControl.o` depend on `HeatingUnit.o`). But you need to put them **together** into the final executable (this is called "linking").

```
TempControlTest: TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.o HeatingUnit.o
        g++ -o TempControlTest TempControlTest.cpp HeatingUnit.o BangBangControl.o
```

In the line above, `TempControlTest.cpp` will be itself compiled, and then linked together with the two already-compiled objects on which it seems to depend into one executable.

NB: when you get an "Undefined reference" error, it generally means your code compiles fine but was missing a symbol it needed to be linked against.

NB2: your makefile rules don't cause the cpp files to depend on the headers they use. That means when you change a header and run "make", make will tell you everything's already built. That's bad.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This worked perfectly! I'm surprised that including HeatingUnit.o in the dependency is necessary, though; I thought that it would be covered in the BangBangControl.o rule.

Comment: There's two things going on there, the dependency alone won't get you a linked binary.  The dependency only tells Make that the object on the left of the : is interested in changes to everything listed on the right.  The g++ call is what actually does the work, and you need to list out all object files (.o) needed for the binary to execute.

Comment: Excellent, thanks everyone. @Borealid - do you happen to know how to make dynamic libraries out of the BangBangControl and HeatingUnit classes? I have a second makefile that creates static libraries, and now I need dynamic libraries. I would really appreciate any help on the subject. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick, if you know how to make a dynamic library from those classes, I would welcome your help as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your executable depends on its source code *and* another object, you need to link in the object as well. You can change your first (real) rule to something like (you may also need `HeatingUnit` stuff in both the dependency list and the `g++` command):

```
TempControlTest: TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.o
    g++ -o TempControlTest TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.o
```

You should also keep in mind that you may need dependencies on *header* files as well. Without that, a change to `BangBangControl.h` would not rebuild `BangBangControl.o` or `TempControlTest`.

And, this is personal preference, I *always* make every rul depend on the `makefile` file as well so that, if I change the makefile, everything gets rebuilt automatically.

Based on all your file contents, I would have something like:

```
# Non-file rules (all is default).

all: TempControlTest

clean:
    rm -rf *.o TempControlTest

# Build executable from all objects.

TempControlTest: makefile TempControlTest.o BangBangControl.o HeatingControl.o
    g++ -o TempControlTest TempControlTest.o BangBangControl.o HeatingControl.o

# Build objects from source (C and headers).

TempControlTest.o: makefile TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.h
    g++ -c TempControlTest.cpp

BangBangControl.o: makefile BangBangControl.cpp BangBangControl.h HeatingUnit.h
    g++ -c BangBangControl.cpp

HeatingUnit.o: makefile HeatingUnit.cpp HeatingUnit.h
    g++ -c HeatingUnit.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
all: TempControlTest

TempControlTest: TempControlTest.cpp BangBangControl.o HeatingUnit.o
    g++ -o TempControlTest BangBangControl.o HeatingUnit.o TempControlTest.cpp 

BangBangControl.o: BangBangControl.cpp BangBangControl.h
    g++ -c BangBangControl.cpp

HeatingUnit.o: HeatingUnit.cpp HeatingUnit.h
    g++ -c HeatingUnit.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o TempControlTest
```

Be sure to make the indentation tabs if that formatting is lost on the page...

Comment: I put this in a new makefile called Makefile_Executable2, then ran "make -f Makefile_Executable2", and I get one line back: "Makefile_Executable2:4: *** missing separator.  Stop." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure the space in front of all the rules is a TAB not 4 spaces, looks like that formatting is lost when you copy/paste.

Answer (score -1):

you can replace this line

```
BangBangControl.o: BangBangControl.cpp HeatingUnit.o
```

with

```
BangBangControl.o: BangBangControl.h BangBangControl.cpp HeatingUnit.o
```

Comment: Why? What problem does this solve? "Magic code" is not helpful, *especially* not for a homework question.